# Using wndproc in C# to minimize form on leftclick of taskbar

Tags: c#, taskbar, minimize, wndproc

I have a C# application that is using wndproc to get a message for a right click to the taskbar, but I also need to use a left click to the taskbar so that I can minimize my form.  The message value for right click on taskbar icon is WMTaskbarRClick = 0x0313.  Does anyone know what the message value is for left click on taskbar icon?

Comment: Are you sure that there *is* such a message?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.  I just figured that if there was one for right clicking on the taskbar icon that there might be one for left clicking on it.

Comment: @Aaron: Can you tell us how are you using "WndProc" to get a message for a right click to the taskbar"?

Comment: The working solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180609/how-to-minimize-form-from-taskbar)

Answer (score 1):

[This link may have the information you seek.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153460/add-to-right-click-application-menu-in-taskbar-in-net)

[Another link](http://www.google.com/search?q=taskbar+left+click)

FWIW: I don't know that you *should* minimize a form when the taskbar is left clicked. The default behaviour should be to minimize a form whose taskbar button is left clicked and Windows handles that for you.

Comment: I have my FormBorderStyle set to None so in this case Windows is not handling it because I have disabled that functionality.  That is why I am looking for a way to do it with sending a message through wndproc.