# WPF Minimize on Taskbar Click

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, minimize

I have a WPF application that by stakeholder requirement must have a WindowStyle="None", ResizeMode="NoResize" and AllowTransparency="True".  I know that by not using the Windows chrome, you have to re-implement many of the OS window-handling features.  I was able to create a working custom minimize button, however I was not able to re-implement the feature where Windows minimize the application when you click on the Taskbar icon at the bottom of your screen.

The user requirement is such that the application should minimize on taskbar icon click and restore on clicking again.  The latter has never stopped working but I have not been able to implement the former.  Here is the code that I am using:

```
    public ShellView(ShellViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the ViewModel as this View's data context.
        this.DataContext = viewModel;

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ShellView_Loaded);
    }

    private void ShellView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var m_hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        HwndSource.FromHwnd(m_hWnd).AddHook(WindowProc);
    }

    private IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == NativeMethods.CS_DBLCLKS)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
            // handled = true
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx
    /// </summary>
    internal class NativeMethods
    {
        public const int SC_RESTORE = 0xF120;
        public const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;
        public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
        public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        public const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
        public const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000;
        public const int CS_DBLCLKS = 0x8;
        NativeMethods() { }
    }
```

Comment: I almost forgot, I have searched StackOverflow before posting and have not been able to find an acceptable solution that works for WPF.  I have seen solutions for WinForms.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the native methods to minimize and restore from the taskbar. Almost all of my applications run this way and I haven't run into this... Does `WindowState = WindowState.Minimized` not work?

Comment: @FlyingStreudel   The problem is that there is not a managed way to detect when the user clicks on the Taskbar.  In all other instances I can minimize and maximize fine, but I don't have a way for the application to respond to the click event of it's taskbar icon.  The requirement is to minimize on taskbar button click.

Comment: I guess I am confused, even with WindowStyle=None and AllowsTransparency=True. The window should still respond to clicks on the taskbar. Is there something else that is preventing that?

Comment: @FlyingStreudel  This link is for WinForms but the same reasoning is true for WPF.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180609/how-to-minimize-form-from-taskbar

I just opened Expression Blend and created a new application with no changes just WindowStyle="None", AllowsTransparency="True".  If ResizeMode="NoResize" it doesn't work but if I don't change ResizeMode it works all of a sudden.  Very strange.

Comment: What operating system? Works just fine on Windows 7 without extra work, so I'm guessing XP, possibly Vista?

Comment: @Joel B Fant, currently i'm only testing in Windows 7.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `ResizeMode="CanMinimize"`. This will allow you to minimize to the taskbar.

Comment: thanks a lot wasting a lot of time i will do this. in my code resize mode has no resize.

Answer (score 3):

I have used this code in the past to minimize/maximize Windows using WPF's `WindowStyle=None`

```
private void MinimizeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
}

private void MaximizeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AdjustWindowSize();
}

private void AdjustWindowSize()
{
    if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
    {
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }
    else
    {
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
}

private void FakeTitleBar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            AdjustWindowSize();
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow.DragMove();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not handle the Taskbar icon being left-clicked.

Comment: @masenkablast - Sorry, just noticed you were referring to TaskBar behavior, not TrayIcon behavior. Isn't the Taskbar behavior part of Windows, not the application?

Comment: It is, however if you set all three of those properties in the question, you disable the Windows behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that if ResizeMode=NoResize than this happens, if it is equal to CanResize than you do not disable the OS feature to minimize via Taskbar icon click.  I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: An alternative to disabling Resizing, is to set the Window's `MinHeight`/`MaxHeight` and `MinWidth`/`MaxWidth` equal to the same.

Comment: @Joel B Fant, that just seems shady to me.

Comment: @Rachel That sounds like a good idea.  The main reason Resizing is disabled is because if you have a chromeless window and maximize the window, if resized is enabled the OS crops pixels off your window where it expected a resizer grip.

Comment: Perfectly normal around here, as the purpose is that if somebody else has a similar problem and finds your question, they also find the solution.