# How to make Form1 appear / disappear when clicking icon on taskbar?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

1. Open notepad in the your computer.
2. Click notepad icon on task bar once.
3. Click notepad icon on task bar once.
4. Click notepad icon on task bar once.

As you can see whenever you click notepad icon on task bar, notepad window appear / disappear.

I have written windows form application program using vb.net language.

How to make Form1 appear/disappear like notepad example?

I didnt find any icon event within Form1 events.

I dont know how to use following code when clicking the icon on taskbar.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe i don't understand you but...isn't that the default behaviour for ALL apps in windows?

Comment: @Pikoh: If it is default behaviour why my Form1 does not?

Comment: We don't know, you haven't given much information. Can you at least post the designer code for your form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens by default for any window that is minimizable. It is built into the window manager.

Your code will interfere with it. Remove the tampering with the `WindowState` property in the `Click` event handler. You do not need to set the `WindowState` to make this happen.

Just make sure that your form's `MinimizeBox` property has not been inadvertently set to `false` (the default is `true`, which is what you want). Note that, in order to be minimizable, the form's `FormBorderStyle` property must be set to either `FixedSingle`, `Sizable`, `Fixed3D`, or `FixedDialog`. Naturally, if the form's properties are configured such that it is non-minimizable, the window manager will not be able to automatically minimize and restore it when you click on its taskbar button.

---

If you insist on allowing a borderless form to be minimized, then you can hack around it. At least, [according to me several years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5180893/366904); I didn't retest the code.

In your form class, override the `CreateParams` method and force the `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` style to be set:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000;

        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style |= WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Not recommended—the user will have a hard time figuring out that your window is actually minimizable since it lacks the telltale button. In general, disabling a form's border is only useful in cases where you're not actually using it as a window (*e.g.*, when you're overlaying it on top of another form for special effects). If it's appearing on the screen as a window, it should look and act like  a window, which means that it's going to need to have a border.

Comment: This is my Form1 setting: FormBorderStyle: None

Comment: That is not in the list of supported border styles. Forms without borders don't have minimize buttons on their title bars because they don't have title bars. This is why your form is behaving differently from Notepad. The Notepad window has a border and can be minimized.

Comment: I changed FormBorderStyle from Sizable to None intentionally. So, is there any other solution without making FormBorderStyle: Sizable?

Comment: If you are wondering why I make FormBorderStyle: None, because I want borderless form.

Comment: Yes, I could tell that much from the name of the property. :-) Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Its obvious that the question code is in Visual Basic .NET.
The provided answer is correct but not in VB.Net

The reason why would it be needed to have this answer; if you are building your application without default resizable form.

For example, if you are making an application where you need to draw your own title bar with your own close/maximize/minimize button and so on... While you don't want to make your application fill the whole client desktop (Full Screen).

This answer is useful for totally customized form style and behavior.

The line & parameter I was looking for is **`cp.Style = cp.Style Or &H20000`**

While this question appear top in Google Search and Hopefully other developers might need to refer to a quick answer and snippets , to save some hours.

The code for Visual Basic .NET looks like this:

```
    Public Class Form1
    ''''' Your code here
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As Windows.Forms.CreateParams
            Get
                Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
                ' cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H2000000 
                ' This is for example to remove graphics flickering if you heavily 
                ' embed images in form1
                cp.Style = cp.Style Or &H20000  
                ' This to restore normal behavior even if you set 
                ' your FormBoarderStyle = None 
                Return cp
            End Get
        End Property

    End Class
```

Thank you for this question and @Cody Gray answer.

Comment: **Note:** I wonder why some would vote down for such a good question. If some have capability to do so; that doesn't mean they can abuse it. It appear that a quick vote down _mouse click_ much easier for some than reading the full scenario and provide some useful hint.

Comment: Warning: `cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H2000000 ` can give you some very unexpected result if your system is too busy doing something.